# how do I get a variable to randomly output one of four words

Tags: c++, visual-c++

//for example, what code would I use to make  wordone output one of four words randomly

cout<< " Once apon a time there was a "<< wordone <<  " who wanted to "<

Answer (score 1):

Assign `wordone` a random value beforehand. For instance,

```
switch(rand() % 4) {
    case 0: wordone = "foo"; break;
    case 1: wordone = "bar"; break;
    case 2: wordone = "ni";  break;
    default: wordone = "knight"; break;
}
```

Of course, the random number generator should be seeded (see [the example on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand)), and `wordone` should be declared (I managed to make it work as a `std::string`, but if you haven't learned that, then you can use `char *`).

Comment: This works well, but depending on your use case, [`std::uniform_int_distribution` should be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32860886/1753435). Side note: Don't use `char *` for strings in C++. If you reall have to, use at least a `const char*`!

Comment: @andreee I agree, but I assume this is a programming assignment, and I've seen introductory texts that still start students off with `char *`, so I offered an alternative that the questioner could actually use. I don't remember `const char *` in such cases, but generally I'm working with students of my own who are taking first-year CS courses. It's a bit surprising to me that at least one first-year CS course hasn't been updated at least to C++11: it's as if the faculty **want** the students to learn bad programming techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Put the words in an [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Then use e.g. [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to get a number between `0` and `3` (inclusive) as index into the array, and use that string.

Comment: what u talk about . i think u can write some codes . or u can watch Learn more about formatting

Comment: @許維德 My goal is not to teach copy-paste programming. My goal is to make people do some research, and learn how to think for themselves. Now, you made your point, please stop pestering me.

Comment: i think u copy too.please stop pestering me. that i want to say .u vote -12 bad question to me. and 4 my questions u talk garbage word to me .