# Random ABCD char generator

Tags: c++, random, char, numbers

I am making a quiz game and want when the player calls his friend(which is a simple cout), the program prints a random char of an answe(A, B, C or D) and a random number to present how sure he is(from 1 to 100). Whetever I try the char in console is always D, and the number is always 87. I don't know how to make this work. This is the current code:

```
char x = *("ABCD" + rand() % 4);
int y = 1+ (rand() % 100);
```

Comment: `rand()` is a pseudo random number generator in a deterministic way. Meaning, given a seed it generates same sequence. Also, `If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.`

Comment: `rand() % someMaximum` doesn't provide good distribution, by the way – better (though you possibly need to ensure no overflow occurs) is `rand() * someMaximum / RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random numbers generation is not as simple as you might think.
See here some general info: [Random number generation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).

In order to use [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) properly, you should initialize the random seed (see the link).
Using the current time as seed is recommended for getting "nice" random values. Note that setting the seed using `srand` should be called only once.

Below you can see a fixed version for your code, that produce different values (potentially) in each run:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Call once:
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    
    // Can be called multiple times:
    char x = *("ABCD" + rand() % 4);
    int y = 1 + (rand() % 100);
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**However** - since C++11 the standard library has good and modern support for random generators. See: [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).
It requires a bit more boilerplate, but you have better control over the generation of random values. See more info in the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header, which contains a lot of classes and utilities.

A good alternative to `rand()` in your case is the [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).
Here is some info why to prefer it over the old `rand()`: [What are the advantages of using uniform_int_distribution vs a modulus operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860654/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-uniform-int-distribution-vs-a-modulus-operation).

The code below shows how to use it in your case (the initilization of `rd`, `gen`, `distrib1`, `distrib2` should be done only once):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Call once:
    std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib1(0, 3);   // For getting a random integer in the range 0..3
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib2(1, 100); // For getting a random integer in the range 1..100

    // Can be called multiple times:
    char ABCD[] = "ABCD";
    std::cout << ABCD[distrib1(gen)] << ',' << distrib2(gen) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```